# How did we deal with correction promoting sound yet non-standard spelling?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, interesting-tags

In the post originally termed: "[What is the difference between a causal system and a memory system?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/78562/15892)", someone corrected the term "memory system" to "memoryful", as opposed to memoryless. And this was validated (while I was hesitating, way to long, to modify or reject the edit). I threfore suggested in comments that "memory system" or "non-memoryless system" were the only versions I have heard of.

But... what shall we do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard term for a system with memory: a *dynamic* system. So the title could have been either

> What is the difference between a causal system and a system with memory?

or

> What is the difference between a causal system and a dynamic system?

No need to invent any extra terms.

---

PS: After checking the original post, it appears that my first suggestion has already been agreed upon.

Comment: Ok,  memoryful was corrected in the meantime